# Mounted new drive and "lost" data

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mount

I have mounted a new drive to a folder within my home directory (/home/mediapc/Downloads/) as I was running low on storage.

I used the following command:

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /home/mediapc/Downloads/
```

Once I did this I lost the data that was in the folder but it has not cleared it from my hard drive.

Is there a simple way to either:

1. Get this data back
2. Actually clear it from my hard drive as currently ubuntu believes I still have 1% of storage left even though it has now gone

I have tried using the `find` command for files I know were in that folder and also using the `du` command but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to do this. I unmounted the drive and my old folder reappeared. I then moved it to another location (Downloads Old) and then remounted.